# Constant Sampling rate Acclerometer android?

Tags: android, sensors

I am working on an application where I need to sample it at constant 30 Hz. Is it possible?
I looked in to the android's SensorManager which provides 4 different sampling rates but none of them give uniform reading.

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Why not do it manually. Set a `Thread` to wake every 33 ms (30 Hz) and get the Accelerometer reading at these times.